# How to sort a list of inter-linked tuples?

Tags: python, list, sorting, tuples, topological-sort

```
lst = [(u'course', u'session'), (u'instructor', u'session'), (u'session', u'trainee'), (u'person', u'trainee'), (u'person', u'instructor'), (u'course', u'instructor')]
```

I've above list of tuple, I need to sort it with following logic....
each tuple's 2nd element is dependent on 1st element, e.g. (course, session) -> session is dependent on course and so on..

I want a sorted list based on priority of their dependency, less or independent object will come first so output should be like below,

```
lst = [course, person, instructor, session, trainee]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for what's called a [topological sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting).  The wikipedia page shows the classic Kahn and depth-first-search algorithms for it; Python examples are [here](http://www.bitformation.com/art/python_toposort.html) (a bit dated, but should still run fine), on [pypi](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/topsort/0.9) (stable and reusable -- you can also read the code online [here](http://www.radlogic.com/releases/topsort.py)) and [here](http://www.logarithmic.net/pfh/blog/01208083168) (Tarjan's algorithm, that kind-of also deals with cycles in the dependencies specified), just to name a few.

Answer (score 4):

Conceptually, what you need to do is create a [directed acyclic graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph) with edges determined by the contents of your list, and then do a [topological sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_ordering) on the graph. The algorithm to do this doesn't exist in Python's standard library (at least, not that I can think of off the top of my head), but you can find plenty of third-party implementations online, such as http://www.bitformation.com/art/python_toposort.html

The function at that website takes a list of all the strings, `items`, and another list of the pairs between strings, `partial_order`. Your `lst` should be passed as the second argument. To generate the first argument, you can use `itertools.chain.from_iterable(lst)`, so the overall function call would be

```
import itertools
lst = ...
ordering = topological_sort(itertools.chain.from_iterable(lst), lst)
```

Or you could modify the function from the website to only take one argument, and to create the nodes in the graph directly from the values in your `lst`.

**EDIT**: Using the `topsort` module Alex Martelli linked to, you could just pass `lst` directly.