# Finding any allowable sorting of a list of "chained" tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, topology, topological-sort

I have a list of 2-tuples called `x`. The 2-tuples can be anything, as long as the first element of the tuple is equal to the second element of the previous tuple in the list. For example with integers:

`x = [(0,150),(150,170),(170,158),(158,170),(170,0),(0,150)]`

The first element of the first tuple and the last element of the last tuple are unconstrained. Now this list is for some reason scrambled:

`xs = [(170,0),(150,170),(170,158),(0,150),(158,170),(0,150)]`

and I wish to sort it so that I recover the original sorting, i.e. `x = sort(xs)`. Note that if there are potentially several ways to sort the scrambled list so that the chained condition above holds, I dont care and am simply interested in one such solution - but I can be sure that at least one solution does exist.

I had a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3146700/how-to-sort-a-list-of-inter-linked-tuples) but to me it seems topological sort is not suitable given that I could have cycles in my graph. So far I have only managed to brute force a solution:

```
import itertools
import numpy as np

def brute_chain_sort(scrambled):
    starts, ends = zip(*scrambled)
    starts = np.asarray(starts)
    ends = np.asarray(ends)
    for permutation in itertools.permutations(range(len(scrambled))):
        permutation = np.asarray(permutation)
        solved = (starts[permutation][1::] == ends[permutation][:-1]).all()
        if solved:
            return permutation
    print("No sorting exists!")

scrambled = [(170,0),(150,170),(170,158),(0,150),(158,170),(0,150)]
idx = brute_chain_sort(scrambled)
starts, ends = zip(*scrambled)
unscrambled = list(zip(list(np.asarray(starts)[idx]), list(np.asarray(ends)[idx])))

print(unscrambled)
# [(0, 150), (150, 170), (170, 158), (158, 170), (170, 0), (0, 150), (150, 1)]
```

Comment: The problem is that `sort` and `sorted` rely on transitive relations, that is, if `x <= y` and `y <= z`, then `x <= z`. However, that's not the case for your tuples. One might try to define `t1 < t2` as `t1[1] == t2[0] or t2[1] == t1[0]`, but that's not transitive. Just because `(0, 150)` comes before `(150, 170)` and `(150, 170)` comes before `(170, 158)` does *not* mean `(0, 150)` can come before `(170, 158)`. This is *not* a sorting problem.

Comment: @chepner Yes I agree with you, I struggled to find the correct terminology for this type of task, and to me in non technical speak the solution required one to "sort" the elements. What type of problem would you describe this as, and do you have any intuition about an "optimal" solution? To me it seems like there are some "connections" to try first since they may be the only ones that are compatible, and that can reduce the search space.

Comment: This is a [Hamiltonian path problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path_problem). Your graph has tuples as its nodes, and the edge `(x,y)` exists if `x[1] == y[0]`.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have enough experience with implementing graph algorithms, the hard part of solving problems like these is just identifying which classical graph problem you can model it as.

Topological sorting was a good idea, but your problem is not a topological sorting problem because the graph is not acyclic. More importantly, it is not a topological sorting problem because the requirement is about which elements must be *adjacent* in the resulting sequence, whereas topological sorting is about which elements must appear *anywhere* before or after which other elements.

---

The problem can be modelled as finding an [Eulerian path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_path), meaning a path which travels every edge of a graph exactly once (necessarily visiting some vertices more than once). The vertices in this graph are the numbers, and the (directed) edges are the tuples.

There is a straightforward way to find an Eulerian path if one exists, which is only made slightly more complicated by the fact that the graph is directed. If a path travels every edge, it is necessarily the case that every vertex has the same number of edges coming in as going out, except possibly a starting vertex with one more edge going out and an ending vertex with one more edge coming in, if the path does not start and end in the same place. From this observation, [Hierholzer's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_path#Hierholzer%27s_algorithm) for finding an Eulerian path can easily be adapted to work for a directed graph. This algorithm runs in linear time in the number of edges, O(E).

---

@chepner notes in the comments that the problem can also be modelled as a [Hamiltonian path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path) problem. Unfortunately, finding Hamiltonian paths is much harder than finding Eulerian paths, and there aren't efficient algorithms. Nonetheless, @chepner is correct.

Comment: Ty for this - I definitely need to read up on graph theory.

Comment: On further reflection I realise that I may be misinterpreting the definition of a Eulerian path: we are in agreement that we want to visit each edge exactly once, however in my example I have repeated edges, i.e. in my example the edge (0,150) is repeated twice. Does this invalidate the classification of this problem as a Eulerian path finding problem?

Comment: As long as you count both copies of the edge when counting the in-degree and out-degree of the vertices, that's no problem.